# Stack reflection in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: elisp, debug

Are there reflection methods available in elisp to examine the stack without invoking the debugger?

For example:

- Get the calling/callee function
- Get the function call stack
- Get the (longer) nested statement stack
- Get arguments for any of the above

An aside: In my search for applicable features/functions/variables I was surprised to learn that elisp does not (natively) perform tail call optimization!  Presumably elisp does then maintain a complete stack.

Comment: See `called-interactively-p` for a function doing this.  I generally recommend against doing such a thing as it's error-prone, incredibly hard to read and lispy languages don't have the need for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer : the function `backtrace-frame` should be what you want.

How did I find this ? Well, here are the steps :

1. invoke the elisp info manual (my favourite way is `C-h r TAB RET`), then
2. search `stack` in the index via `i stack RET`.

The first result brings you to `(info "(elisp) Internals of Debugger")` which mentions `backtrace-frame`. I think this has all you want.

You can also look at the implementation of the debugger in `debug.el`, e.g. with `M-x find-function RET debug RET` if you have the sources installed.